QGIS2Web 3 plugin - image does not appear
I have successfully used QGIS2Web 3 plugin to create a webmap, but the attached images are not appearing in the webmap popups.
I have a small database of sites, two of which have attached images linked in the attribute table. The attached images are stored on my computer, and appear in the desktop QGIS popup when 'Attribute forms' is selected. When I use the qgis2web plugin to create an OpenLayers map, the resulting website appears perfectly fine, but the images are not shown in the popup, instead the webmap produces an 'image' icon, but not the actual image. I have researched this extensively, tested changing various parameters, and also followed the instructions on this previous github post https://github.com/qgis2web/qgis2web/issues/661, but nothing works. Please can someone suggest how I can get my images to appear in the webmap popup.
My only remaining thought was that the popup appears quite narrow compared to the webpage and I wondered if that was affecting it, but I cannot figure out how to make the popup wider either.
You can see the webmap at https://hpethen.github.io/EES_Delta_Survey_Test/
If anyone knows what mistake I've made then please let me know.

You can consult the documentation at this address: https://qgis2web.github.io/qgis2web/#setLayers
This is specifically described in the Image or Video subchapter:
Image or Video
If you want to show images or video in popup you must set Widget Type to "Attachment" and do not change other values. Only the Absolute path is supported:

Set the absolute path as the field text:

The result in your map will look like this

or this, for video

For the width of the popup you can edit the qgis2web.css file present in the "resources" folder of your export. Increase these values
    th {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
    td {
        min-width: 100px;
    }

Warning: the popup would probably be larger if you exported with the full-screen template rather than canvas-size. You can find the option in the Appearance tab of the plugin.

With thanks to the previous poster, I have solved this. I have an internal C drive and a D Drive on my computer. I had the attachments (as well as all the other QGIS data) on my D drive, as that's the SSD. When I moved the attachments to the C Drive and linked to the new C drive filepath in the attributes table the attachments worked perfectly in Qgis2web. So if you have attachments and they aren't appearing I suggest you shift them to your C drive if they are stored elsewhere.
